# I get a error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need help. My dependency is following:

```
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '3.0.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context-support'
```

I get the error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/StandardServletEnvironment`

Is there something wrong with my dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's in `spring-web`, which is a dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web`. Here you've overridden `spring-web` with a very old Spring Framework version. That's the source of your problem.